# Rest API to retrieve the read access shared link for a file in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there any rest API to fetch the read access shared link for a fresh file added to SharePoint using the rest API?

Below is the Create File Rest API

`url: http://siteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/FolderName')/Files/add(url='a.xlsx',overwrite=true)
method: POST
body: "Contents of file in raw plain text"
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-length:length of post body`

Now the task is to get the shared read access link for a.xlsx

Comment: Sorry, Please clarify your question. If I understand correctly - You have added new file within rest api call and now you need to retrieve link to this file? If yes - please provide your call for creating the file.

Comment: Apologies, edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the REST API below to achieve it.

```
https://sitecollectionurl/_api/SP.Web.CreateAnonymousLink
```

**Example code**:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    anonymousAccessLink();
});
function anonymousAccessLink(){
    var _selectedFileName = "a.xlsx";
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Web.CreateAnonymousLink";
    $.ajax({
        'url': url,
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': JSON.stringify({
            'url': _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/FolderName/' + _selectedFileName,
            'isEditLink': false
        }),
        'headers': {                                                                                                         
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
        },
        'success': function (data) {
            var resultData = data.d.CreateAnonymousLink;
            console.log(resultData);
        },
        'error': function (result, status) {                                                                                                 
            console.log("Ajax anonymous access :-"+JSON.stringify(result)+' - '+ status);
        }
    }); // End of ajax anonymous access.
}
</script>
```

**Refer to**: [Rest Api Generate Guest Link SharePoint Online](https://reshmeeauckloo.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/create-anonymous-link-sharepoint-online-rest/)